# Angular UI-router Неопределенное состояние

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Пункты меню выглядят как

```
<a ui-sref="state1">Label</a>
```

Меню формируется автоматически, состояния подставляются из массива.
Как сделать так, чтобы для некоторых (не всех) пунктов меню состояние было фиктивным, т.е. при клике на ссылку переход не происходил бы. Например, просто открывалось бы подменю, а страница сайта не менялась.
Варианты: void(0), не существующее состояние, состояние со свойством abstract:true, - вызывают ошибку.
Сделать обратный переход в resolve не получается, т.к. исходное состояние уже потеряно. (или нет?)

Уточнение к комментарию Grundy:
Предложение сделать так:

```
<a ui-sref="state"   ng-if="state!==void(0)" >Label </a> 
<a ng-href="void(0)" ng-if="state===void(0)" >Label </a>
```

Приводит к удвоению кода. Label в моем случае содержит код, который придется повторить дважды. Не хотелось бы.
Также не хотелось бы отказываться от ui-sref. 
Можно было бы сделать так:

```
<a ng-href="path" >Label </a>
```

где

```
path=[path1, path2, void(0)]
```

Но хочется сделать на ui-sref.

Видимо, надо еще пояснить.Вариант:

`<a ng-href="path" ng-repeat="path in [path1, path2, void(0)]">Label </a>`

можно, но не хочется.
Хочется что-то типа:

```
<a ui-sref="state" ng-repeat="state in [state1, state2, void(0)]">Label </a>
```

Но на это angular выдает ошибку, т.к. $staite не может быть void(0).
Вот я и хотел бы создать фиктивное состояние, которое никуда бы не переводило, аналогично href="void(0)"

Comment: стоит просто поменять формирование меню и там где переход не нужен не добавлять эту директиву

Comment: Не айс. Потребуется удвоить код. 
<a ui-sref="state" ng-if="state!==void(0)" >Label</a>
<a ng-href="void(0)" ng-if="state===void(0)" >Label </a>
Label в моем случае содержит код, который придется повторить дважды. Не хотелось бы.
Также не хочется отказываться от ui-sref.
Можно было бы, конечно, обойтись ng-href. Где нужен переход, подставить путь, где не нужен - void(0).
Но хочется сделать на ui-sref.

Comment: Весь необходимый код для демонстрации нужно добавить непосредственно в вопрос. Как можно заметить в комментариях он абсолютно нечитаем

Comment: набор  `path=[path1, path2, void(0)]` ты сам формируешь?

Comment: `.` ведет на тот же самый роут на котором сейчас

Comment: @Grundy. Поскольку других ответов нет, то можно ли Ваш ответ сформулировать так:
"ui-route не дает возможности создать фиктивное состояние. Поэтому, в данном случае надо пользоваться не ui-sref, а ng-href".
Если это так, то я перенесу данное утверждение в ответ и закроем тему.

Comment: выше в комментарии я писал, что можно использовать `.` в качестве имени состояния, она соответствует текущему состоянию

Comment: @Grundy Извини, не заметил. В контексте комментария подумал, что речь идет о предыдущей фразе. Проверил - работает!!! Почему же ты не выставил это как ответ на вопрос?

Comment: Ну если работает тогда хорошо :-)

Answer (score 4):

Ответ найден, благодаря @Grundy. Состояние с именем '.' и есть то самое искомое состояние. В итоге имеем:

```
<a ui-sref="state" ng-repeat="state in [state1, state2, '.', state4]">Label </a>
```

Плохо вчера посмотрел, данное решение является непригодным, т.к. angular все равно пытается перейти в данное состояние (с именем '.') и выдает ошибку, оставаясь, правда, в исходном состоянии.

Но выход все же найден.

1. Создаем рабочее состояние в минимальной комплектации.

   .state('layout.fix', {
                   views: {

   ```
               },
               resolve: {
                   path: function(){console.log('Im chost'); return true; }
               }
           })
   ```

Такое состояние angular воспримет как корректное. По нему даже можно перейти.

2. В блоке .run() вставить перехват смены состояния:

```js
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
 function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams,  options){ 
  if(fromState.name != '' &&  toState.name == 'layout.fix'){
   event.preventDefault(); 
  }
 });
```

Таким образом, если это не изначальная загрузка fromState.name != '' и переход идет на фиктивное состояние, то отменяем переход.